# Bootstrap, Roots theme - Gap on right hand side at mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Here's my site,
http://www.superfastgoose.com/

I've built the template using roots, and for the life of me i cannot figure out why there is gap on the right at media below 768px.

Initially you don't see the gap on page load but you're able to scroll to the right.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I cant see the gap ??

Comment: Use Bootstrap 3.2 or 3.3 (latest) 3.0 (what you're using) had this scroll bar problem but it was last year so my memory might be faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try adding this CSS to your stylesheet, hopefully it'll solve the issue:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .container {
         width: 90%;
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to simply define `overflow-x: hidden` for the `body` if the website is accessed with a device whose screen size is smaller than 768px, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
         overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the first suggestion was what got it working great stuff.